# Create a custom auth provider that authenticate through an external API?

Tags: laravel, rest, api, authentication, jwt

I'm new to Laravel.

I already have an API that authenticates users and creates a JWT token for it. Now in my new app, I want to outsource *authentication* and *authorization* to this API.

this new app acts like a front-end for the API, and API handles the logic of app.
I'm not completely familiar with this type of architecture, but I think it's a 3-layer architecture that has been divided physically.
the main problem for me is to handle authentication of users and how to turn the stateless logic of API into a web app.

Should I create a custom auth provider?
How? could you provide an example!

Comment: This is actually mostly in the docs already, have you taken a look at https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/authentication#adding-custom-user-providers ?

Comment: I didn't understand the docs, and btw it's not about API!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks to everyone,

But the final solution was *Creating a middleware* that handles authentication. for example, the middleware authenticates user through a form and saves the JWT token on a session.

this easy step solved my all problems.

Comment: hi alireza.. could you provide your middleware class for reference?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is creating a custom guard.  [See docs here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/authentication#adding-custom-guards).

Comment: could you explain how it works? sorry, but I'm new to laravel

Comment: The guard handles all auth logic in Laravel and are defined in your `config/auth.php`.  When creating a custom guard driver you register it in that config file and make sure that class implements this interface https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.3/src/Illuminate/Contracts/Auth/Guard.php.  To authenticate in Laravel with your custom guard driver, set your custom guard as the default guard in that config or reference it directly in your `Auth` facade like `Auth::guard('custom')->check($credentials)`